# Бесконечная прокрутка вверх как в чате предыдущих сообщений

Tags: css, jquery

Друзья. Не могу решить проблему бесконечной прокрутки **предыдущих** сообщений в чате.

Вроде работает, но выводит не  правильно. Не в той последовательности. Решение где-то на поверхности, но блин.... не могу решить.

при нажатии на "Предыдущие сообщения" (#prev-mess) первый раз ajax подгружает блоки правильно - выше предыдущих #im-dialog-prev, а последующие нажатия вставляет **ниже** предыдущих, хотя хочется выше. Как это победить?

```js
$(document).ready(function($)
  {
  $(".im-dialog").animate({ scrollTop: 20000000 }, "slow");
  });


var block_show = false;

function WatchMore()
  {
  var $target = $("#showmore-triger");
  if (block_show)
    {
    return false;
    }
  var page = $target.attr("data-page");
  page++;
  block_show = true;

  $.ajax({
    url: "/new/im/ajax/previus_messages.php?id=26675&page=" + page,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data)
      {
      $(".im-dialog #im-dialog-prev").append(data);
      block_show = false;
      }
    });
  console.log("/new/im/ajax/previus_messages.php?id=26675&page=" + page);

  $target.attr("data-page", page);
  if (page >=  $target.attr("data-max"))
    {
    $target.remove();
    }
  }

$("#prev-mess").click(function()
  {
  WatchMore();
  });
```

```css
.im-dialog
  {
  height:300px;
  padding:0 8px 0 0;
  margin:16px -8px 16px 0;
  overflow:auto;
  }
.im-dialog-left
  {
  float:left;
  max-width:85%;
  background-color:#f4f4f4;
  border-radius: 0 12px 12px 12px;
  padding:12px;
  border:1px solid #f0f0f0;
  }
.im-dialog-right
  {
  float:right;
  max-width:85%;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  border:1px solid #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 12px 0 12px 12px;
  padding:12px;
  }
.clearer {clear:both;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="im-dialog">
<div id="showmore-triger" data-page="1" data-max="3"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="prev-mess">предыдущие сообщения</a></div>

  <div id="im-dialog-prev"></div>

  <div class="im-dialog-left">
      текст текст текст 
  </div>
  <div class="clearer"></div>

  <div class="im-dialog-right">
      текст 2 
  </div>
  <div class="clearer"></div>

  <div class="im-dialog-left">
      текст3 текст4 текст 4
  </div>
  <div class="clearer"></div>

  <div class="im-dialog-right">
      текст 4 
  </div>
  <div class="clearer"></div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hibinyru/xw3cd8k2/7/

PS. ну и если вдруг будет время , подскажите, пожалуйста, еще как сделать чтобы в текущем div с диалогами при нажатии "предыдущие сообщения" был автоматом скрол на нижнее сообщение открывшегося из ajax блока?

Comment: так `prepend` мб  нужен вместо `append` ?

Comment: @teran а ларчик открывался просто, спасибо большое!

Comment: оформил ответом. опечаткой закрывать вопрос вроде не совсем уместно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы используете метод `append`, который добавлвяет контент в конец блока, а требуется добавлять в начало. Для этого есть метод `prepend`.